# validation using jquery

Tags: jquery

The below link has my web page and i would like to validate all the fields using jquery, the problem is I dont have much space around the fields to display ordinary error messages. I am am a novice and thinking of using jquery validation, so could any of you suggest me the best possible way to do that.
http://www.4shared.com/photo/BowU9nFB/page.html

Thanking You,

Indranil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the jQuery plug-in [Ketchup](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/) it uses little floating talk bubbles so not as much space is needed.

Comment: This is nice.  I've never seen this plugin before.  Sweet!

Comment: Hey Adam, i tried the validation but the alignment of the whole page gets altered..what to do? pleae help

Comment: @Indranil What do you mean by the alignment? Can I see a screenshot? You may want to try asking for help at Kethup's support site http://github.com/mustardamus/ketchup-plugin/issues

Comment: hey thanx 4 the reply Adam,
Its the CSS problem and i m trying to figure it out, but in the mean time i encountered another problem:(

I am using jgrowl on the same page where i am trying to validate the fields at the same time now the problem is both are jquery and are mutually exclusive..what to do?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery plugin: Validation is pretty straight forward and configurable.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Limit the messages or use jQuery UI Dialog to notify the end user of the errors.  No space needed.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

There is a flexible jQuery validation system to show error messages in any format you want.

**Full doc** at [jQuery Validation System](http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/14/jQuery-Validator-Plugin-Validation-Plugin-.html)

more samples at http://www.tectual.com.au/downloads/jquery/validation/index.html

So you can have your validation errors in a **popup**, **tooltip** or **anywhere else in the page**.

You can also extend the validator methods as well.